# What priority should I give to a script running on startup?

Tags: linux, shell-script, startup, gpio

I 'm running Angstrom distribution on an embedded device. I want to make use of its GPIO expansion ports, that are set to be high on start-up. Below, is the code segment, that releases an expansion port.

```
#!/bin/sh

cleanup() { # Release the GPIO port
  echo 133 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
  exit
}
```

I 'm thinking of running this script on startup, using `update-rc.d name_of_script default`.

***My question is:***

What priority should I give in order to ensure that GPIO ports won't get high on startup? I assume that there is a script responsible for GPIO ports getting high. If this is true, I could instead, disable it from running on startup.

*For any additional inforamtion (e.g. contents of `/etc/init.d`), please let me know.*

Comment: Priority? Are you talking about the numbers in front of the scripts in /etc/rcX.d?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, `update-rc.d name_of_script default` has sequence number 20. By priority I mean this sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Angstrom is using dependency-based boot or not. If they are, the numbers are ignored. Let's assume they're not.

The numbers are strictly for ordering the scripts. It's important (for example) to make sure all the filesystems are mounted before trying to start the web server. Or to make sure syslogd is started before starting most daemons.

So, in your case, it needs to come after (higher number) any scripts which load the GPIO drivers, but before (lower number) the script starting your app (which depends on the GPIO port configured correctly).

If, as above, its using dependency-based boot, then you set the dependencies correctly in the comments at the top of the script, and update-rc.d should figure out a number for you (possibly renumbering other scripts as well, to make it all work).